# Image won't appear on JLabel. Tried multiple solutions

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm trying to add an image to a JLabel to put on JFrame and after hours of researching it still only loads the JFrame with 2 buttons on the bottom. The Image in question is in the same directory as the class except a folder down (I've tried in the same folder to no avail). I'm quite new to coding so please bear with me.

This is most of the code except the button's action listeners (the class extends JFrame as well)

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JPanel jb = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 20, 20));
JLabel jl = new JLabel();
JButton end = new JButton("End");
JButton next = new JButton("Next");

jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("notes/daWay.jpg"));

setSize(900, 700);
jp.add(jl, new FlowLayout());
add(jp);
jb.add(end);
jb.add(next);
add(jb, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

setVisible(true);
```

I've tried: setting label bounds, checked if ImageIcon was null (it wasn't), making ImageIcon its own variable then adding the variable to the Jlabel, getContentPane for JFrame, using a BufferedImage and ImageIO with try and catch (with url and without), getClass, getClassLoader, getResource, imageUpdate on the label, with FlowLayout and without, jpegs and pngs, clearing the frame except for the one label, and many other things. Even extending the window while running the image doesn't appear, Please Help!

(also in the future I'd like to clear the label and add a new image, I'm not at that point yet cause I can't get past this error but if context helps with the solution then context)

Comment: `ImageIcon` is probably a bad place to start, as it won't tell you when something goes wrong.  A better place (to hep you diagnose the issue) would be to use `ImageIO.load` - see [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Comment: Also, set the text of the label to make sure it's actually been added to your frame

Comment: `jp.add(jl, new FlowLayout());` doesn't make sense.  In this case, just use `jp.add(jl);`

Comment: I added the FlowLayout cause I knew it wouldn't hurt and Eclipse gets weird sometimes so it was just to make sure that wasn't the problem. I'll try ImageIO when I get home and let you know, Thank You!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added text to the JLabel and it just displays the text at the top of the JFrame, I tried ImageIO like you suggested and got a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

The [ImageIcon constructor you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.lang.String-) takes a **file path** as an argument.

For your code to work, you would thus have to pass an absolute file path, because relative ones are resolved based on the **current** directory, not based on the class containing the file path.

The current directory is the directory from which the java command is executed.

What you want to do is use the class loader to load the image. So that you can embed the image into the jar file you will create when building your application.

So you should instead use

```
new ImageIcon(YourClass.class.getResource("notes/daWay.jpg"))
```

This will load the image from the daWay.jpg resource located in the subpackage `notes` of the package of `YourClass`.

Comment: I usually have better luck using the leading `/`, like `"/notes/daWay.jpg"` to make the path 'package agnostic' with regard to the calling class..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at targetPractice.Trumpet.<init>(Trumpet.java:37)
 at targetPractice.TargetPractice.main(TargetPractice.java:20)

Comment: But I've checked if the image was "null" using different methods online, all came back with some form of data

Comment: How do you build your code (which IDE, build tool, etc.). Where precisely is the .java file located and where precisely is the image located.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, the .java file for my main and my class are in their own folder on my hard drive, and the notes folder is in that same folder as well. I'm new to coding so I don't know what a build tool is :(

Comment: Then your image is probably not named daWay.jpg. Or your code is not as it should be. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, by editing your question.

Comment: In my post is ALL of my code other than Action Listeners for the buttons and the class extending JFrame. The only thing in my main calls an Obj of my class (which I know works because when I run the program a Frame appears with 2 buttons (with Action Listeners working) and no image). I know for a fact the image is named "daWay.jpg" (it's the only thing in the folder "notes") I've tried everything I could find online (things I tried in my post above) and I can't do the entire file directory starting from C because this program is meant to run on a separate computer after it's wrapped as an exe.

Comment: So you haven't changed your code at all, despite my answer?

Comment: I added your answer to my code and got the error I posted in the comments